# How did the fusion of Chromosome 2 spawn a separate smarter species?

Tags: human-genetics, mutations, chromosome, human-evolution

I’m familiar with the evidence that two primate chromosomes fused into human Chromosome 2, and I understand that primates with such a mutation could still breed with those without it.

My question is, was it just a coincidence that the primates with 23 pairs became a smarter species branch?  Or did the mutation somehow enable our ancestors to become more intelligent than their relatives in the same biome?

Early on, the 23s must have coexisted with and interbred with the 24s.  But at some point, they became too genetically distant to breed.  So they must have genetically separated when they were still capable of interbreeding.
Was that separation because the 23s were somehow better able to adapt to new habitats or lifestyles that the 24s weren’t able to follow them to?